# Transitioning and autoscrolling divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a HTML page with different sections. Each section is contained within a DIV. My requirement is to make transition between each divs. For Eg, after couple of seconds, section1 blurs out and section2 blurs in and so on. Now within a particular section I want the section contents to autoscroll until the end of the section is reached, from bottom to top. I am able to create toggle between different sections but am not able to scroll the contents of each section, so that for eg, the first section autoscrolls and when the end of section is reached, it only then goes to another section and then scrolls that. Can anybody please help me with this? I have paste my code at below link,

http://pastebin.com/rE8h5NK0

Also, I have given fixed position to each section heading but when I minimize the page the heading doesnt align correctly. And if I do not have it fixed, it is not properly visible on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest running JQuery `scrollTop` in a loop, looking for when the scrolling reaches the bottom by matching the `div`'s height minus the container's height with the amount scrolled:

```
function scroll() {
    if ($('#div').scrollTop() == $('#div').height() - $('#container').height()) {
        scrollInterval.clearInterval();
        // Transition to next section
    } else {
        $('#div').scrollTop($('#div').scrollTop() + 1);
    }
}

var scrollInterval = setInterval(scroll,20 /* Scroll speed */);
```